# Validate Expression Success with if condition in powershell

Tags: powershell, boolean, try-catch, powercli

I am attempting to run a long PowerCLI command in a powershell script and output to the console based on its success. The command is executing and succeeding but NOT triggering the success output.

I tried making the entire command a variable but with no success. I suspect there is a more advanced way to do this that I am just not aware of.

```
Try{      
        #get list of all vms
        Write-Host "Collecting data and adding to file..."
        [Environment]::NewLine
        #create list of VMs in a variable
        $vmList = Get-VM -ErrorAction Stop


        #collect the VMWare Disk List here.
        #run the list through the appropriate filters and prompt for success (failure will initiate the catch)
        if ($vmList | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOff" -and $_.ExtensionData.config.ManagedBy.ExtensionKey -ne 'com.vmware.vcDr'} | Select-Object Name, @{N="Disk (GB)"; E={[math]::Round(($_ | Get-HardDisk | Measure-Object CapacityGB -Sum).sum)}}, @{N="Power State"; E={$_.PowerState}} | Export-Csv -Append -LiteralPath c:\temp\VMdiskTotals.csv) {
        Write-Host "vCenter Disk Collection for " $vcenter " Successful!"
        }

        }
Catch{
            Write-Host "Failed to collect the data from " $vcenter.Vcenter -ForegroundColor Red
            }
```

I want this to run the command, and if it completes with no error to output:

"vCenter Disk Collection for " $vcenter " Successful!"

if the command produces ANY error, it should trigger the catch and output:

Write-Host "Failed to collect the data from " $vcenter.Vcenter -ForegroundColor Red

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Why are you putting so much into the `if` statement? Can't you just move it before the `if` statement? What specifically is the `if` statement being used for in this scenario?

Comment: I am using it to validate  that the command succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not clear why you need to put everything in an if statement. But perhaps this would work for you:

```
try {
    $vmList = Get-Vm -ErrorAction Stop
    if ($vmList) {  # If there are any VM objects in the array
        "vCenter Disk Collection for $vcenter Successful!"
        $vmList | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOff" -and $_.ExtensionData.config.ManagedBy.ExtensionKey -ne 'com.vmware.vcDr'} | 
            Select-Object Name, @{N="Disk (GB)"; E={[math]::Round(($_ | Get-HardDisk | Measure-Object CapacityGB -Sum).sum)}}, @{N="Power State"; E={$_.PowerState}} | 
            Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\VMdiskTotals.csv -Append -ErrorAction Stop
        "Successfully outputted to file."
    }
    else {
        "No VMs found."
    }
}
catch [VMware.VimAutomation.Sdk.Types.V1.ErrorHandling.VimException.VimException] {
    "Search for VMs failed."
}
catch [System.IO.IOException] {
    "Unable to write to file."
}
catch {
    "Other catch."
    $Error[0]
}
```

Comment: This is very close to where I have ended up as well. The problem I am having is that if the nested catch is triggered, the out one is too. That doesn't make sense but is what keeps happening. Getting close to just giving up. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Which exceptions are you getting?

Comment: I modified the code to not use nested try/catch, but rather to catch the specific exceptions. See if that helps. Your VMware exception may be named differently depending on what version of PowerCLI you are using.

Comment: that does work. I wasn't aware that catches were cascaded... seems odd. This type of extreme granularity worked though and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could do this is to capture that info in a variable within your `If` statement, then in the script block for that have it output to CSV and write to the console.

```
    if (($ToOutput=$vmList | Where-Object {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOff" -and $_.ExtensionData.config.ManagedBy.ExtensionKey -ne 'com.vmware.vcDr'})){
        $ToOutput | Select-Object Name, @{N="Disk (GB)"; E={[math]::Round(($_ | Get-HardDisk | Measure-Object CapacityGB -Sum).sum)}}, @{N="Power State"; E={$_.PowerState}} | Export-Csv -Append -LiteralPath c:\temp\VMdiskTotals.csv
        Write-Host "vCenter Disk Collection for " $vcenter " Successful!"
    }
```